# Ruby on Rails render array of objects plus number of elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails method with this render:

```
render :json => @boats, :include => { :mainPhoto => {:only => [:id, :mime]},
                                           :boat_model => { :only => :name, :include =>  {:boat_type => { :only => :name}}}}
```

Can I include a numTotal variable in this response?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `as_json` method to serialize `@boats` in separated JSON key:

```
render :json => { numTotal: boats.size, boats: @boats.as_json(:include => { :mainPhoto => {:only => [:id, :mime]},
                                           :boat_model => { :only => :name, :include =>  {:boat_type => { :only => :name}}}})
```

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I think your code is missing a "}" at the end. Anyway, I don´t know why Angular (which is calling the Rails API method) is returning an error when I use your approach: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at copy (angular.js:593)
    at new Resource (angular-resource.js:350)
    at angular-resource.js:407
    at forEach (angular.js:137)
    at angular-resource.js:406
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:6846)
    at angular.js:6883
    at Object.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:8057)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:7922)
    at Object.$get.Sco...

Comment: Hi Rober, I think that Angular expects an Array of `@boats`. Anyway, I don't know Angular well...

Comment: Yes, I think so. Right now, my only approach is to add the numTotalBoats as attribute inside the boats.